# Why is openCV moveWindow function not working?

Tags: python, opencv

Below, I have a python script. The part that is not working is the function cv2.moveWindow("TrackBars", WIDTH, 0).
I haven't a clue why it isn't working because I can use the moveWindow function on my other "my Cam" window.
I initialized the "TrackBars" window and resized it before I try to use the moveWindow function.
The point of the script is to make a camera window and have another window with inputs that change the position of a circle that is drawn on the camera window.

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=480
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"))

xPos = WIDTH//2
yPos = HEIGHT//2
radius = 25
def setX(x):
    global xPos
    xPos = x
def setY(y):
    global yPos
    yPos = y
def setRadius(r):
    global radius
    radius = r
cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars", 250, 100)
cv2.moveWindow("TrackBars", WIDTH, 0)
cv2.createTrackbar("xPos", "TrackBars", WIDTH//2, WIDTH, setX)
cv2.createTrackbar("yPos", "TrackBars", HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT, setY)
cv2.createTrackbar("radius", "TrackBars", 25, HEIGHT//2, setRadius)
while True:
    ignore,  frame = cam.read()
    cv2.circle(frame, (xPos, yPos), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('my WEBcam', frame)
    cv2.moveWindow('my WEBcam',0,0)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
```

Comment: I don't believe I can actually resize the TrackBars window either. This might a problem for Mac users since I can't really do anything with the trackBar window after initializing it.

Comment: yeah the `highgui` stuff, when you use trackbars, is somewhat broken, in multiple backends, not just macos. IIRC there's an issue already on the github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of initiating the TrackBars window with cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars"), I found that initiating the window with `cv2.imshow("TrackBars", np.zeros([10,10], dtype=np.uint8))` worked for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you can move "TrackBars" window, but can't move "my WEBcam" window, because you used fixed coordinate values in the while loop:

```py
while True:
    ...
    cv2.moveWindow('my WEBcam',0,0)
    ...
```

If you want to move the window, just comment out the line:

```py
while True:
    ...
    # cv2.moveWindow('my WEBcam',0,0)
    ...
```

In addition, to make the "TrackBars" window on top of the "my WEBcam" window, you need to add one more line:

```py
cv2.namedWindow("my WEBcam")
cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
```

I've modified the code to test the "TrackBars" window:

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=480
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"))

xPos = WIDTH//2
yPos = HEIGHT//2
radius = 25
windowX = 0
def setX(x):
    global xPos
    xPos = x
def setY(y):
    global yPos
    yPos = y
def setRadius(r):
    global radius
    radius = r

def setWindowX(x):
    global windowX
    windowX = x

cv2.namedWindow("my WEBcam")
cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars", 250, 200)
cv2.moveWindow("TrackBars", windowX, 400)
cv2.createTrackbar("xPos", "TrackBars", WIDTH//2, WIDTH, setX)
cv2.createTrackbar("yPos", "TrackBars", HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT, setY)
cv2.createTrackbar("radius", "TrackBars", 25, HEIGHT//2, setRadius)

# Test moveWindow
cv2.createTrackbar("moveWindow", "TrackBars", 25, HEIGHT//2, setWindowX)

while True:
    ignore,  frame = cam.read()
    cv2.circle(frame, (xPos, yPos), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('my WEBcam', frame)
    cv2.moveWindow('my WEBcam',0,0)
    cv2.moveWindow("TrackBars", windowX, 400)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
```

**macOS**

[image]

**Windows**

[image]

Comment: My apologies. Whenever I say I want to move the window, I mean I want to use the function cv2.moveWindow(), not move it with my cursor. I will be more clear in my question.

Comment: @Alekk I've tested your code. There's no problem to use `moveWindow()`  to move  the "TrackBars" window. You can try adding a trackbar to change the coordinate values of the window.

Comment: Do you have a Mac or something else? I have a feeling that this might be OS related.

Comment: @Alekk I've tested the code on Windows and macOS.

Comment: well I'm flabbergasted. I tried your code and I had the camera window under the trackbar window but the trackbar window was still at the top left.

Comment: through random debugging I figured out that I need to initialize the TrackBar window with cv2.imshow("TrackBars", np.zeros([10,10], dtype=np.uint8)), not cv2.namedWindow

Answer (score 1):

Move the window after creating it.

```
cv2.imshow("window_name", image)
cv2.moveWindow("window_name", 800, 0)
```